# Python - Find K max values in each row of one matrix and compare to binary matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to determine if the position (index) of the k largest values in matrix a are in the same position as the binary indicator matrix, b.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[.8,.2,.6,.4],[.9,.3,.8,.6],[.2,.6,.8,.4],[.3,.3,.1,.8]])
b = np.matrix([[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1]])
print "a:\n", a
print "b:\n", b

d = argsort(a)
d[:,2:] # Return whether these indices are in 'b'
```

Returns:

```
a:
[[ 0.8  0.2  0.6  0.4]
 [ 0.9  0.3  0.8  0.6]
 [ 0.2  0.6  0.8  0.4]
 [ 0.3  0.3  0.1  0.8]]
b:
[[1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]

matrix([[2, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]])
```

I would like to compare the indices returned from the last result and, if `b` has ones in those positions, return the count.
For this example, the final desired result would be:

```
1
2
2
1
```

In other words, in the first row of `a`, the top-2 values correspond to only one of the ones in `b`, etc.

Any ideas how to do this efficiently? Maybe the argsort is the wrong approach here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Saullo's huge help, I was able to take his work and reduce the solution to three lines. Thanks Saullo!

```
#Inputs
k = 2
a = np.matrix([[.8,.2,.6,.4],[.9,.3,.8,.6],[.2,.6,.8,.4],[.3,.3,.1,.8]])
b = np.matrix([[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1]])
print "a:\n", a
print "b:\n", b

# Return values of interest
s = argsort(a.view(np.ndarray), axis=1)[:,::-1]
s2 = s + (arange(s.shape[0])*s.shape[1])[:,None]
out = take(b,s2).view(np.ndarray)[::,:k].sum(axis=1)
print out
```

Gives:

```
a:
[[ 0.8  0.2  0.6  0.4]
 [ 0.9  0.3  0.8  0.6]
 [ 0.2  0.6  0.8  0.4]
 [ 0.3  0.3  0.1  0.8]]
b:
[[1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
Out:
[1 2 2 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you take the `argsort` you get it from minimum `0` to maximum `3`, so you can reverse it doing `[::-1]` to get for maximum `0` and for the minimum `3`:

```
s = np.argsort(a, axis=1)[:,::-1]   
#array([[0, 2, 3, 1],
#       [0, 2, 3, 1],
#       [2, 1, 3, 0],
#       [3, 1, 0, 2]])
```

Now you can use `np.take` to get the `0`s where the maximums are and `1`s where the second-maximums are:

```
s2 = s + (np.arange(s.shape[0])*s.shape[1])[:,None]
s = np.take(s.flatten(),s2)
#array([[0, 3, 1, 2],
#       [0, 3, 1, 2],
#       [3, 1, 0, 2],
#       [2, 1, 3, 0]])
```

In `b`, the `0` values should be replaced by a `np.nan` so that `0==np.nan` gives `False`:

```
b = np.float_(b)
b[b==0] = np.nan
#array([[  1.,  nan,  nan,   1.],
#       [  1.,  nan,   1.,   1.],
#       [  1.,   1.,   1.,  nan],
#       [  1.,  nan,  nan,   1.]])
```

and the following comparison will give you the desired result:

```
print np.logical_or(s==b-1, s==b).sum(axis=1)
#[[1]
# [2]
# [2]
# [1]]
```

The general case, to compare the `n` biggest values of `a` against a binary `b`:

```
def check_a_b(a,b,n=2):
    b = np.float_(b)
    b[b==0] = np.nan
    s = np.argsort(a, axis=1)[:,::-1]
    s2 = s + (np.arange(s.shape[0])*s.shape[1])[:,None]
    s = np.take(s.flatten(),s2)
    ans = s==(b-1)
    for i in range(n-1):
        ans = np.logical_or( ans, s==b+i )
    return ans.sum(axis=1)
```

This will do pair-wise comparisons in the `logical_or`.

Comment: Saullo, thanks for your answer, but running your code, I get `[2,2,1,2]` as the output. Also, I would like to generalize to k>2. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @zbinsd Sorry! I've updated the answer... in here I forgot to put `[:,::-1]` to reverse the original `argsort` result...

Comment: Saullo, this is getting really close. How can I get, say, the top-3? I eventually (for a bigger matrix, `a`), need to return the top-10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the same concept, but the `np.logical_or` has to be changed... I will update the answer for a general case...

Comment: @zbinsd please, accept the other answer which is much faster and simpler than this one...

Answer (score 1):

Anothen simpler and much faster approach, based on the fact that:

`True*1=1, True*0=0, False*0=0, and False*1=0`

is:

```
def check_a_b_new(a,b,n=2):
    s = np.argsort(a.view(np.ndarray), axis=1)[:,::-1]
    s2 = s + (np.arange(s.shape[0])*s.shape[1])[:,None]
    s = np.take(s.flatten(),s2)
    return ((s < n)*b.view(np.ndarray)).sum(axis=1)
```

Avoiding the `0` to `np.nan` conversion, and the Python `for` loop that makes things pretty slow for a high value of `n`.

Comment: Saullo, this gives: `matrix([[5],[5],[6],[5]])` for the input: `check_a_b_new(a,b,n=2)`